# Facebook verb pending approval

Tags: javascript, facebook-opengraph

I'm getting stuck with how to publish to facebook verb + object. In particular, does anyone know a single application that has this feature implemented?

All my verbs are pending approval.

When I try to issue:

```
FB.api('me/daparadarseapp:Use' 
        + '?Minita=http://daparadarseapp.com/POCStreamLinePublish.html','post',
        function(response) 
        {
            if (!response || response.error) 
            {
                alert('Error occured');
                alert( dump( response ) );
            } 
            else 
            {
                alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
            }
        });
```

I get:

> 'error' ...
>   'message' => "Unknown path components: /daparadarseapp:Use"
>   'type' => "OAuthException"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

use the beta of the JS-SDK as long as your verbs are still pending.

```
<script src="http://connect.beta.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```